# MonacaのOnsen UIでcurrentTimeを動作させる方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, monaca, onsen-ui

MonacaのOnsen UI最小限のテンプレートで開発しているのですが、currentTimeが動作しません。
http://docs.monaca.mobi/ja/sampleapp/samples/#6

currentTimeで再生位置を0にし、音声ファイルを先頭から再生できるようにしたかったのですが、動作せず困っています。

currentTimeが動作しない場合audio.pause(); audio.src = audio.src;で動作すると書いてあり試しましたがダメでした。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966724/html5-audio-currenttime-doesnt-work

実装したいことは、再生した音声ファイルを停止後、再度再生する時に先頭から再生できるようにすることです。

現状実装できていることは、
・音声ファイルの再生
・音声ファイルの停止
です。
ons-back-buttonタグとons-buttonタグをonclickするとページ遷移し音声ファイルが停止する仕様です。
解決方法を教えていただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

index.html

```
<script>
    ons.bootstrap();

    function sound(){
       //[ID:sound-file]の音声ファイルを再生[play()]する
        document.getElementById("sound-file").play();
    }

    /* currentTimeが動作しません
    function soundpause(){
       //[ID:sound-file]の音声ファイルを停止[pause()]する
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("sound-file").pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0;
        },10);
    }
    */

    /* currentTimeが動作しません
    function soundpause(){
       //[ID:sound-file]の音声ファイルを停止[pause()]する
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("sound-file").pause();
            ("sound-file").currentTime = 0;
        },10);
    }
    */

    /* currentTimeが動作しない場合audio.pause(); audio.src = audio.src;で動作すると書いてあり試したが動作しない
    参考 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966724/html5-audio-currenttime-doesnt-work
    function soundpause(){
       //[ID:sound-file]の音声ファイルを停止[pause()]する
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("sound-file").pause();
            audio.src = audio.src;
        },10);
    }
    */

    /* currentTimeが動作しない場合audio.pause(); audio.src = audio.src;で動作すると書いてあり試したが動作しない
    参考 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966724/html5-audio-currenttime-doesnt-work
    function soundpause(){
       //[ID:sound-file]の音声ファイルを停止[pause()]する
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("sound-file").pause();
            ("sound-file").src = ("sound-file").src;
        },10);
    }
    */

</script>
```

```
<!-- 音声ファイルの読み込み -->
<audio id="sound-file" preload="auto">
<source src="se/sound.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

page2.html

```
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left"><ons-back-button onclick="soundpause()">Back</ons-back-button></div>
    <div class="center">Page 2</div>
</ons-toolbar>

<a onclick="sound()"><ons-gesture-detector style="height: 100%;">
<div style="text-align: center">

    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <ons-button
        onclick="soundpause();myNavigator.popPage()">
      Pop Page
    </ons-button>

</div>
</ons-gesture-detector></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function soundpause(){
   //[ID:sound-file]の音声ファイルを停止[pause()]する
    setTimeout(function(){
        var soundFile = document.getElementById("sound-file");
        soundFile.pause();
        soundFile.currentTime = 0;
    },10);
}
```

soundpause()の処理をこんな感じにしてみたらどうでしょうか？
一応こちらではそれっぽい動作が確認できました。

Comment: 動きました！ありがとうございます！少し書き方が間違えていたんですね。勉強になりました！

Comment: @lootre 本回答で解決した場合には回答を承認して下さい。よろしくお願いします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers